# Group and sub group with linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a class T with members `ProductId`, `CategoryId`, `CategoryName` and `DateLastModified`.
What I'd like to achieve is to create a new list of an anonymous type (just going to loop through it in my view) that firstly groups on `CategoryName` then groups the `CategoryNames` by `DateLastModified.Year & DateLastModified.Month`

So far I have

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.CategoryName });
```

Where list is my `List<T>`

This groups by categoryName as key with the elements, just not sure on the next step

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to group once on 3 keys or group in 3 levels?  (OK, 2 levels)

Comment: Twice, firstly group on categoryName, then group the CategoryName by Year/Month combo

Comment: do you want this only with linq?

Comment: I'm open to any solutions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Nested Group in that case, Try this:-

```
 var query = from pro in products
                       group pro by pro.CategoryName into newGroup1
                       from newGroup2 in
                           (from prod in newGroup1
                            group prod by new { prod.DateLastModified.Year, prod.DateLastModified.Month } 
                           )
                       group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JI73kq).

Comment: Thanks for that, I had to come up with a botched solution. I initialised two lists grouped the first one by CategoryName and having a count within a select new, second list grouped by CategoryName, DatePublished.Month, DatePublished.Year and also  having a count in a select new. Then created a joinedLists joining on CategoryName (will always be unique) having a select new from this joined list having   CategoryName = .CategoryName,
            catsTotal = c.TotalCatCount,
            Month = m.Month,
            MonthTotal = m.TotalMonthCount. Messy but it worked. Your's is much cleaner :)